# Unity Rewarded and Interstitial Ads

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

how do i stop the time and music while an ad is playing or does unity handle that by itself?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found an old forum post about ads...

https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-do-i-pause-the-game-while-the-ads-are-showing.332757/

> "When running your app on device, the Unity Player will pause while
> Unity Ads are shown. However, if you are testing in the Unity Editor,
> the game is not paused while the placeholder ads are shown.
>
> You could handle this by pausing audio playback and setting the timescale to > 0 while showing. Then un-pause the audio and restore the timescale value
> after the ad placeholder is closed."

So:

`Time.timescale = 0;`

and something like:

`Camera.main.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Pause();`